Is there a way to open these crates?
I've come across these crates once or twice:

and they look ever so tantalising, with their blue lights and "open me" aura.
Is it possible to open them? How?

...oh. Well, that was easy.
So if you continue a little past the crate in the photo (it's right in the beginning of the game, to the left of the toilet and the save point, opposite the stasis recharger), there'll be a little thing you can read that says to open them, just foot-stomp them by pressing space.
Didn't think I'd find it that fast.
